# Custom avro message deserialization with Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, flink-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

The Flink consumer application I am developing reads from multiple Kafka topics. The messages published in the different topics adhere to the same schema (formatted as Avro). For schema management, I am using the Confluent Schema Registry.

I have been using the following snippet for the KafkaSource and it works just fine.

```
KafkaSource<MyObject> source = KafkaSource.<MyObject>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
                .setTopics(TOPIC-1, TOPIC-2)
                .setGroupId(GROUP_ID)
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(MyObject.class, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL))
                .build();
```

Now, I want to determine the topic-name for each message that I process. Since the current deserializer is ValueOnly, I started looking into the setDeserializer() method which I felt would give me access to the whole ConsumerRecord object and I can fetch the topic-name from that.

However, I am unable to figure out how to use that implementation. Should I implement my own deserializer? If so, how does the Schema registry fit into that implementation?

Comment: I think you want a `KafkaPartitionSplit` object after the `KafkaSource`, not mess with the deserializer. Regardless if you have both keys and/or values, the topic name should still be available in other places. Also worth pointing out that `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` will work for keys as well

Comment: @OneCricketeer how do you serialize/deserialise key and value both  as part of kafka source and sink function

Comment: I mean without implementing custom serializations/deserializations.

Comment: @JayGhiya I'm not familiar with the Flink API, but you will need to specify deserializers for both keys and values. If Flink doesn't offer them, then you need to write your own, or find an external dependency that does.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setDeserializer` method with a `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema` that might look something like this:

```java
public class KafkaUsageRecordDeserializationSchema
        implements KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema<UsageRecord> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private transient ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    public void open(DeserializationSchema.InitializationContext context) throws Exception {
        KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.super.open(context);
        objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
    }

    @Override
    public void deserialize(
            ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord,
            Collector<UsageRecord> collector) throws IOException {

        collector.collect(objectMapper.readValue(consumerRecord.value(), UsageRecord.class));
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<UsageRecord> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(UsageRecord.class);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `ConsumerRecord` to access the topic and other metadata.

Answer (score 1):

I took inspiration from the above answer (by David) and added the following custom deserializer -

```java
KafkaSource<MyObject> source = KafkaSource.<MyObject>builder()
          .setBootstrapServers(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS)
          .setTopics(TOPIC-1, TOPIC-2)
          .setGroupId(GROUP_ID)
          .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
          .setDeserializer(KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema.of(new KafkaDeserializationSchema<Event>{                                                          
    
           DeserializationSchema deserialzationSchema = ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific(MyObject.class, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

           @Override
           public boolean isEndOfStream(Event nextElement) {
              return false;
           }
        
           @Override
           public String deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord) throws Exception {
              Event event = new Event();
              event.setTopicName(record.topic());
              event.setMyObject((MyObject) deserializationSchema.deserialize(record.value()));
              return event;
           }
        
           @Override
           public TypeInformation<String> getProducedType() {
              return TypeInformation.of(Event.class);
           }
           })).build();
```

The Event class is a wrapper over the MyObject class with additional field for storing the topic name.